# can not log in to ftp since plesk upgrade

Tags: authentication, ftp, passwords, plesk

Non of my ftp accounts work via ftp since I upgraded to plesk 9.5.4.  I get "*530 login incorrect.*" The username and password are correct since I can see them at both at */etc/passwd* and */etc/shadow*.  I have tried changing the information via **Domains -> mydomain.com -> Web Hosting Settings -> FTP Login** and I still get the error.  If I add a user name or password via *Web Users*, it is added to the password file, but that login does not work either. My root login via SSH works fine.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
-Jonathan

Comment: should be on serverfault, not really a programming question.

Comment: So I have access to all my server files, what DOES need to be changed? The websites display fine in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /var/log/messages for errors from proftpd.

Here is my /var/log/messages for simple FTP session:

```
Jan 16 16:39:15 localhost xinetd[577]: START: ftp pid=9317 from=::ffff:10.50.2.4
Jan 16 16:39:16 localhost proftpd[9317]: 10.52.52.203 (10.50.2.4[10.50.2.4]) - FTP session opened.
Jan 16 16:39:16 localhost proftpd[9317]: 10.52.52.203 (10.50.2.4[10.50.2.4]) - FTP session closed.
Jan 16 16:39:16 localhost xinetd[577]: EXIT: ftp status=0 pid=9317 duration=1(sec)
Jan 16 16:39:16 localhost xinetd[577]: START: ftp pid=9318 from=::ffff:10.50.2.4
Jan 16 16:39:16 localhost proftpd[9318]: 10.52.52.203 (10.50.2.4[10.50.2.4]) - FTP session opened.
Jan 16 16:39:22 localhost proftpd[9318]: 10.52.52.203 (10.50.2.4[10.50.2.4]) - Preparing to chroot to directory '/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld'
Jan 16 16:40:03 localhost xinetd[577]: Exiting...
```